# Eric Matthes alien invasion project, ship will not stay on screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, function, pygame

I am working on the alien invasion project 1 and attempting to write the code for restricting the ships movement so that it stays on the screen. However, this is not happening. I can get the program to work with zero errors but the ship will not stay on the screen. The section that specifically limits the ships movement is under `def update(self):`

Any help would be great, thanks everyone!

```
import pygame 

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        # initialize the ship and set its starting position
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # load the ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('alien_invasion/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # start each new ship at the center of the bottom of the screen
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        # movement flag 
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        # update the ships position based on the movement flag
        # update the ships center value, not the rect
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # update rect object from self.center
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        # draw ship at current location
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

I placed `self.rect.centerx = self.center` at the beginning and at the end of `def update(self):` and everything seems to be working the way it was designed. I'm still unsure of why the code example in the book doesn't produce the same results as the answer shown below. Anymore insight would be great!

```
import pygame 

class Ship():

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        # initialize the ship and set its starting position
        self.screen = screen
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings

        # load the ship image and get its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('alien_invasion/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        # start each new ship at the center of the bottom of the screen
        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

        # movement flag 
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        self.rect.centerx = self.center
        # update the ships position based on the movement flag
        # update the ships center value, not the rect
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor

        # update rect object from self.center
        self.rect.centerx = self.center

    def blitme(self):
        # draw ship at current location
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```